# fopen returning NULL in gdb

Tags: c++, c, gdb, buffer-overflow

Im trying to solve a binary exploitation problem from picoCTF, but I'm having trouble with gdb.
Here is the source code of the problem (I've commented some stuff to help me).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 32
#define FLAG_LEN 64
#define KEY_LEN 4

void display_flag() {
  char buf[FLAG_LEN];
  FILE *f = fopen("flag.txt","r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("'flag.txt' missing in the current directory!\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  fgets(buf,FLAG_LEN,f);
  puts(buf);
  fflush(stdout);
}

// loads value into key, global variables ie not on stack
char key[KEY_LEN];
void read_canary() { 
  FILE *f = fopen("/problems/canary_3_257a2a2061c96a7fb8326dbbc04d0328/canary.txt","r");
  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("[ERROR]: Trying to Read Canary\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  fread(key,sizeof(char),KEY_LEN,f);
  fclose(f);
}

void vuln(){
   char canary[KEY_LEN];
   char buf[BUF_SIZE];
   char user_len[BUF_SIZE];

   int count;
   int x = 0;
   memcpy(canary,key,KEY_LEN); // copies "key" to canary, an array on the stack
   printf("Please enter the length of the entry:\n> ");

   while (x<BUF_SIZE) {
      read(0,user_len+x,1);
      if (user_len[x]=='\n') break;
      x++;
   }
   sscanf(user_len,"%d",&count); // gives count the value of the len of user_len

   printf("Input> ");
   read(0,buf,count); // reads count bytes to buf from stdin

   // compares canary (variable on stack) to key
   // if overwriting need to get the value of key and maintain it, i assume its constant
   if (memcmp(canary,key,KEY_LEN)) { 
      printf("*** Stack Smashing Detected *** : Canary Value Corrupt!\n");
      exit(-1);
   }
   printf("Ok... Now Where's the Flag?\n");
   fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  
  int i;
  gid_t gid = getegid();
  setresgid(gid, gid, gid);

  read_canary();
  vuln();

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this normally, with `./vuln`, I get normal execution. But when I open it in gdb with `gdb ./vuln` and then run it with `run`, I get the `[ERROR]: Trying to Read Canary` message. Is this something that is intended to make the problem challenging? I don't want the solution, I just don't know if this is intended behaviour or a bug. Thanks

Comment: This code produces a warning. You should fix it. Well, 3 if you use `-Wall -Wextra` which you should.

Comment: @klutt This is the source code from the challenge, I didn't compile it or write it

Comment: Is it a setuid program? run `ls -l vuln` - is there a `s` in the permissions?

Comment: It might be interesting to know whether the file is not found or whether the program [running under `gdb`] is denied access. Consider editing the code and switching to (e.g.) `printf("[ERROR]: Trying to Read Canary -- %s\n",strerror(errno));` Or, just put a breakpoint on the `printf` statement and then use `gdb` commands to examine `errno`

Comment: @user253751 yes. Here is the output `-rwxr-sr-x 1 hacksports canary_3 7744 Sep 28  2019 vuln`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want the solution, I just don't know if this is intended behaviour or a bug.

I am not sure whether you'll consider it intended behavior, but it's definitely not a bug.

Your `./vuln` is a set-gid program. As such, it runs as group `canary_3` when run outside of GDB, but as your group when run under GDB (for obvious security reason).

We can assume that the `canary_3` group has read permissions on the `canary.txt`, but you don't.

P.S. If you printed `strerror(errno)` (as comments suggested), the resulting `Permission denied.` should have made the failure obvious.